# ZMQ, Autobahn, Ratchet -> Sometimes not pushing messages

Tags: symfony, nginx, zeromq, ratchet

I'm facing quite an issue and I really don't know what it's caused by at all. A lot of stuff on my website gets done via websockets, for example pushing messages to clients.

For pushing I'm using ZMQ and Ratchet.

This is the php code:

```
                $UserMessage = array(
                    'user' => $userid,
                    'message' => 'Search started',
                );

                $context = new \ZMQContext();
                $socket = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher');
                $socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

                $socket->send(json_encode($UserMessage));
```

This is the push-server:

```
            <?php
            require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$pusher = new Some\Bundle\Topic\Pusher();

// Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onMessage'));

// Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
$webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$webSock->listen(8181, '0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                $pusher
            )
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```

The problem is: sometimes messages don't get pushed AT ALL. This is happening very randomly. Sometimes it works like a charm for 20 messages in a row, sometimes not.

Does anyone have any idea what this might be caused by? I'm using nginx as a webserver by the way. Are there any kind of logs that might help out?

Regards

Comment: Is there anything in any sort of log? It's not normal for ZMQ to send a few messages and then just die, and the code you posted looks "ok" as much as code can look fine without having the actual system in front of you.. Could you post ZMQ version, extension version and PHP versions?

Comment: latest zmq and language binding version. php version is 5.5.9. I've changed the bind to 0.0.0.0:5555 now instea of 127.0.0.1:5555, restarted the server and it works fine. Gonna monitor if it breaks again at some point.

Comment: Yep, making problems again. Restarting the server somehow fixes it for a certain amount of time. This is so weird ...

Comment: If you have php-fpm logs, do check for dead processes or things like that. It's very, very odd for zmq to cause this kind of behaviour. I'm using it extensively and I've never experienced an issue where zmq sends a few messages and then dies. It's usually a signal that either the process which sends or receives dies at some point.

Comment: well, it doesn't really die and it's not even sure what this problem is caused by. It just seems like some pushed messages just...get lost. Sadly the fpm log only shows that config has been loaded.

Comment: and oddly enough restarting the server always fixes it...until it breaks at some point again.

Comment: Since you didn't post your entire code, do you have mechanisms in place that can catch exceptions thrown by ZMQ? Also, after you push the messages, can you log the messages to a file? `file_put_contents('/var/log/zmq_php.log', json_encode($UserMessage), FILE_APPEND);` - if you don't see messages being appended after you push, I'd suspect that file descriptors have been exceeded and that you can't connect any more. Also, try binding to `tcp://*:5555` and connecting via `tcp://127.0.0.1:5555`

Comment: Hi, i've tried logging the messages and it worked just fine. Messages got logged, but client didn't receive it. Controller returns success .... it's not like messages don't get pushed at all, it's that just SOME messages don't get received. If i push f.e. "test" 10 times, 4/10 times the message won't get received.

Comment: Well, without some kind of trace it's difficult to tell you what might be wrong. You can use `tcpdump` to monitor the TCP traffic. If you manage to push but fail to pull and you can see the message being sent  using `tcpdump` then it's easy to determine that ZMQ binding breaks for some reason.

Comment: I've used tcpdump to monitor the traffic on port 5555. When the website didn't have a domain yet, i used the internal (?) name, to connect to it: $socket->connect("tcp://h2277003:5555");. Now pushing via this connection actually resulted in NON-STOP traffic on the port, which caused some messages to not get pushed. When i got the domain i changed everything to 127.0.0.1/localhost ....except for this one controller, which is used to activate/deactivate a certain area of the page. Now that i changed it as well: everything works fine! Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted, and since I've never encountered this scenario before - I'll keep this in mind as well :)